# ChangeDisplaySettingsEx call with CDS_ENABLE_UNSAFE_MODES

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system

What would ChangeDisplaySettingsEx call with CDS_ENABLE_UNSAFE_MODES flag do?

Os page says "Enables settings changes to unsafe graphics modes" which does not make sense.

Can someone please explain in detail?

Thanks..

Comment: It allows you to pick a graphics mode that Windows thinks is not safe to use for the monitor.  In the olden days that could damage the monitor.  These days you'd just get a black screen if the LCD panel doesn't support the mode.

Comment: I did some experiments with this and found out that all the down scaled modes are marked as unsafe by the os. In order to allow downscaling we need to set this flag.

Thanks.